# Is there way to make set consuming less memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, set

This is my code

```
import numpy as np

set_ = set()
n = int(input())
while n > 0:
    set_.add(hash(input()))
    n -= 1
```

Are there simple ways to make the set consuming less memory in two and more times?

Comment: If you want to use a set, it will consume the memory it is designed to. If you want to use less memory, don't use a set.

Comment: How big is your set? If you're using a set that is large enough that you have memory problems, you may want to use something else instead. But that'll depend on the context.